# Problem loading csv files to sql server through visual studio

Tags: sql-server

I am getting below error while loading csv files into sql server (version 12.0.5571), I am using visual studio 10 for uploading data. Below are the errors which I am getting, need some help to figure out where am i going wrong.

> [OLE DB Destination [529]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. 
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005   Description: "Conversion failed when converting
>   the nvarchar value '"201' to data type int.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [529]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.   The "OLE DB
>   Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error
>   code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB
>   Destination. Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (529) failed
>   with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (542).  The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.
>
> [Flat File Source [264]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data
>   Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
>   PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.
>   The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
>   PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
>   component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OLE DB Destination [529]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An
>   OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult:
>   0x80004005 Description: "Conversion failed when converting the
>   nvarchar value '**"201**' to data type **int**.".

The value "201 cannot be converted to INT because it starts with a double quote character.

Perhaps, this is a sign that **text qualifier** to be  as the double quote, similar to:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG118.png]

Otherwise, consider changing the failing column mapping from a numeric to a string type

Comment: @SaibalDutta, nice that the issue was resolved. Can you then mark this post as the accepted answer to your issue, so this thread going to be marked as "answered"